# How do I save a program in kdb/q?

Tags: kdb

Most of the examples seem to be run in REPL mode.  Is it possible to load myprog.q from disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you just need to provide the name of the .q script as an argument to the q process:

```
/opt/app/KX/q2.7/q /opt/app/path/to/script/myprog.q -p 5000
```

would start a q process on port 5000. On startup it will execute the contents of your script.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, from inside a running REPL,

```
\l myprog.q
```

will load the script.

Also note that you can persist the root workspace to disk and resume later:

```
$ q
q)a:1
q)`:workspace set get`.
`:workspace
q)\\
$ q workspace
q)a
1
```